# 5 Day marinated chicken breast

Tags: food-safety, marinade, chicken-breast

Bought chicken breast on Sunday and put in marinade.  It is now Thursday.  Chicken has turned a bit white . . . is it safe to cook and eat at 5 days in marinade?

Comment: What's in your marinade? If it contains any acid (lemon juice or vinegar), the surface may have just "cooked" due to the acid.

Comment: Beside that official word on food safety I linked, we have some questions on marinade duration, they can be found through the search

Answer (score -1):

2 days is usually the max for chicken in the fridge that is officially recommend, 5 days is definitely on the long side.  Pending the sell by date that the chicken had originally.

Color is just the marinade, it's the bacteria you need to be concerned about.  Hard to tell if chicken has gone bad in a marinade.

Good acidic or high salt marinade, you are probably safe.   Really up to you if you want to take the small risk or just throw away.